# Adding python3 packages to Buildroot

Tags: buildroot

**Buildroot** is a tool that can be used for building Linux images for embedded-system boards.

Buildroot comes with a predefined set of Python packages that can me selected from its menu.

In addition, Buildroot is added with a nice Python script that can import any package which is part of the [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) repository, called "scanpypi".

However it seems the script is only adapted to Python2. When trying to import a newer package, errors appear, such as:

```
./support/scripts/scanpypi websockets -o package
buildroot package name for websockets: python-websockets
Package: python-websockets
Fetching package websockets
Downloading package websockets from https://pypi.python.org/packages/b6/12/6194aac840c65253e45a38912e318f9ac548f9ba86d75bdb8fe66841b335/websockets-4.0.1.tar.gz...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./support/scripts/scanpypi", line 653, in <module>
    main()
  File "./support/scripts/scanpypi", line 604, in main
    package.load_setup()
  File "./support/scripts/scanpypi", line 250, in load_setup
    setup = imp.load_module('setup', s_file, s_path, s_desc)
  File "/tmp/scanpypi-qbY6eQ/python-websockets/websockets-4.0.1/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

This one was failing for invalid keyword.

Also:

```
./support/scripts/scanpypi websocket-server -o package
buildroot package name for websocket-server: python-websocket-server
Package: python-websocket-server
Fetching package websocket-server
Downloading package websocket-server from https://pypi.python.org/packages/74/64/e86581ee7775a2e08aca530b41e1a1e3ee6b320233b1eff301dcb86d1636/websocket_server-0.4.tar.gz...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./support/scripts/scanpypi", line 653, in <module>
    main()
  File "./support/scripts/scanpypi", line 604, in main
    package.load_setup()
  File "./support/scripts/scanpypi", line 247, in load_setup
    os.chdir(self.tmp_extract)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/scanpypi-YXROmL/python-websocket-server/websocket-server-0.4'
```

This one was failing for package name containing underscore (_) instead of dash (-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a Python3 porting for scanpypi.

See https://github.com/ishahak/buildroot_scanpypi3

EDIT

By the request of @yegorich, I'm glad to inform that now scanpypi can be used for both Python 2/3!

My linked version can still be used for installing newer versions directly from GitHub.

Comment: I've also converted scanpypi to Py3 (see this [patch](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/813447/)), but the final plan is to make scanpypi executable in both Py2 and Py3 environments. Patches are welcome!

Comment: Well done! I have seen your work but didn't want to change my original python2 script, and didn't know your script's maturity.

Comment: BTW I have noticed that having the package appear under ./package is not enough for seeing it within the Buildroot menu. I had to manually add a line in package/Config.in. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You're not missing anything. For now you have to add the package to `package/Config.in` manually.

Comment: Could you please test this [patch](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/876083/) and report your results to the BR's mailng list? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please update your answer and state, that scanpypi can now be used with both Py2/3? Thanks.